# Why does the formula for decreasing intensity of radiation only work for gamma rays?

Tags: gamma-rays

$I(x) = I_0 \cdot e^{~-u \cdot x}$

Where u is the linear attenuation coefficient

And how does this relate to the following

$N(x) = N_0 \cdot e^{~-u \cdot x}$

Where N is the count rate of the beam typically measured by a GM counter.

Comment: I suggest that you provide more background about why you think that the formula applies to the gamma rays, what specific situation you are talking about, and what $N(x)$ is in your case.

Answer (score 0):

A gamma photon is either absorbed or carries on through matter without being changed. This implies that the probability, $K$, per unit distance travelled of a gamma being absorbed is independent of how far the gamma has travelled. So we have
$$\frac{(–dN)/N}{dx}=K \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{that is}\ \ \ \ \ \ \frac{dN}{dx}=\ –KN$$
Integration leads to the equation you have quoted.

Alphas and betas lose their kinetic energy bit by bit is a series of ionisation events, so the further they have travelled, the slower they get. Eventually they stop. This finite range is quite unlike the exponential fall-off in gamma intensity with distance.

Comment: Ah, thanks for clearing that up. By typing the bottom equation with N instead of I, I was also hoping that someone could explain to me what the reasoning is for the Intensity being directly proportional to the count rate. Or, in other words. I = k*N

Comment: You might define intensity as number of particles crossing unit normal area per second. So if your Geiger-Müller detects a fixed fraction of the gammas that enter it, the count rate will be proportional to the beam intensity. The proportionality will still hold (for a given energy of gamma) if you define beam intensity as *energy* per second per unit normal area.

Comment: In addition, charged particles experience energy loss from both electronic and nuclear stopping, and the relative amounts change with the energy of the particle.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does the formula for decreasing intensity of radiation only work for gamma rays?

**Incorrect**. [Beer–Lambert law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beer%E2%80%93Lambert_law) works for many radiation types, including photons (gamma rays, visible light, ...), neutrons, etc. General form of Lambert law sounds :
$$ A = \varepsilon \ell c $$
Where $A$ is absorbance, $\varepsilon$ is the molar attenuation coefficient, $\ell$ is the radiation path length, and $c$ is is the concentration of the attenuating species.

Absorbance can be defined as :
$$ A=\ln\left(\frac {I_0}{I}\right) $$
Where $I_0$ is incident ray intensity, $I$ - transmitted ray intensity. Substituting this into equation above and using logarithm rules for expressing logarithm argument and making a couple adjustments, gives :
$$ I=I_0 e^{-\varepsilon~ \ell ~c} $$

This is in case attenuation coefficient is uniform in all media, otherwise one needs to integrate with respect to $\varepsilon(\ell)$.